# I donot want to be changed the size of image after saving in android

Tags: android, size

I am an android developer.
I get a image from intenet in my app and then save it in my external storage of my device.but unfortunately android resizes it to a smaller image and I don't want it.here is my code while saving image.

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, int n) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/TinGroup");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();

    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Android SDK does not change image size when compressing. Compare  `finalBitmap.getWidth()`, `finalBitmap.getHeight()` and JPEG's size.

Comment: How you downloaded image from internet?

Comment: yes,I gets it from internet and change it to bitmap by decodestream method